# how to bind or pass the controller scope value as a scope in angularjs custom directive template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually i want to bind or pass the controller scope value as a scope name in angularjs custom directive template.

Here i would like to mention scope name dynamically forming in controller and then assigning value to that scope(dynamically generated scope).

Directive Code:

```
app.directive('webTemplateCreation',function($compile,$timeout){    
    var layoutObj={};   

    linkFn=function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {   
        element.append("<web-template-layout ng-repeat='layout in layoutData.collections.layout.rowset' layout='layout'></web-template-layout>");       
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };
    // isolated scope with layout data, mapper data and page object 
    layoutObj.scope={layoutData:'=',pageObject:'=',mapperData:'=', containerId:'='};
    layoutObj.restrict='AE';
    layoutObj.replace='true';
    // template for creating the layout
    layoutObj.template = "<div "
            + "page-object='[\"layoutObj\"].Data'"
            + "layout-data='[\"pageObj\"].Data'"
            + "mapper-data='mapperObject.Data'  "
            + "container-id='templateContainerId'  "
            + "style='height:100%;' class='row bootstrap480'>"
            + "</div>";

    layoutObj.link = linkFn;

    return layoutObj;    
});
```

// Scope not binding / passing

[\"layoutObj\"] - This is not working. This scope coming from controller

Hope I explained properly. if need more details please update guys.

This method written in controller from here i am passing that object.

```
  $scope.getTemplateToRender = function(templateContainerId, entityName) {

        $tempCEP.fetchLayoutDetailsForRendering(getAttributeName(entityName), function(layoutObject, pageObject, blocklyXML, entityTypeJSON) {

            $scope.layoutObj = 'layoutObject'+templateContainerId;

            $scope[$scope.layoutObj] = {};
            $scope[$scope.layoutObj].Data = {};
            $scope[$scope.layoutObj].Data = layoutObject;

            $scope.pageObj = 'pageObject'+templateContainerId;
            $scope[$scope.pageObj] = {};
            $scope[$scope.pageObj].Data = {};
            $scope[$scope.pageObj].Data = pageObject;               

            $scope.layoutState.state = 'new';
            var entityType = 'website';

            $scope.containerTemplate = true;
            $scope.templateContainerId = templateContainerId;               

            if($scope.containerTemplate == true) {
                var newElement = $compile("<web-template-creation></web-template-creation>")($scope);                   
                angular.element("[containerid="+$scope.templateContainerId+"]").html("");                       
                $element.find("[containerid="+$scope.templateContainerId+"]").append(newElement);

                //$scope.$digest();
             }

            $scope.reinitialize();
        });
};
```

Comment: what is 'layoutObj' ? it is not defined anywhere.should be layoutData? what is 'pageObj'? What is thi type of notation ["layoutObj"].Data is about? should be just layoutObj.Data ? And who shows you this way to write directive? Can not you jest have return {...} - so your local variable not confuses anyone.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - Layoutobj is coming from main controller. that code i have placed. Layoutobj is having one value that value holding another scope name. Please check and update me